# How to convert the code used with dictionary to ES5?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, es5-compatiblity

The code below works well in new browsers with dictionaries like

```
var CRAFT_DB = {
  6: {
    id: "6",
    type: "blockC",
    name: "local name",
    recipes: [{
      type: "new",
      count: "2",
      input: [
        [{
          index: "4",
          count: "1"
        }],
        [{
          index: "21",
          count: "1"
        }]
      ]
    }]
  }
}

var input = CRAFT_DB[6].recipes[0].input;
var ingredients = {};
for (var key in input)
    ingredients[input[key][0].index] = void 0 === ingredients[input[key][0].index] ? parseInt(input[key][0].count) : ingredients[input[key][0].index] + parseInt(input[key][0].count);
```

But I should support ES5. But I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property "index" from undefined` with ES5-enabled browser.

I tried to convert the code to ES5 with https://babeljs.io/repl, but it didn't help.

How could I fix it?

Comment: `input` isn't a variable. This will error (and not with the error you quote) in any JS engine.

Comment: @Quentin do you want to say that I can not use `input` as a variable name? I've corrected the code to show how I define the `input`.

Comment: No, I was saying you hadn't defined `input`

Comment: `var ingredients = CRAFT_DB[6].recipes[0].input.map(function (inp) { return {key: inp[0].index, value: inp[0].count}; }).reduce(function (o, e) { o[inp.key] = o[e.key] || 0 + parseInt(e.value); return o; });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following verification helped me -

```
for (var key in input) {
    if (typeof input[key][0] !== 'undefined') {
      ...
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In earlier versions of JS a lot of the built-in properties on arrays are enumerable.

When you loop over them with `in` you get those as well as the integer indexes.

`input['length']` is going to be undefined, as is `input['push']`.

Use a regular `for (var i = 0; i < index.length; i++)` loop.